# If checkbox is clicked, autoslide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a photo gallery and I want to add the auto-slide functionality but I cant seem to figure out.

This is my code so far : https://codepen.io/reardgjoni/pen/VBBKZq
(begins at line 105 of the Js file)

```
        <div class="arrows">
        <div id="arrow-left" class="arrow">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
         </div>

         <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox"></input>
         </div>

        <div id="arrow-right" class="arrow">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in this line of code:

```
var checkBox = document.querySelector('.checkbox');
```

In this way you select the div and not the checkbox input field. Change that line to:

```
var checkBox = document.querySelector('[type=checkbox]');
```

Your updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/gaetanoM/pen/ejxrLm)

Answer (score 0):

You can `setInterval` to trigger click event of `arrowRight` if checkbox is checked.

Assign `id="autoplay"` to the checkbox.

And then add these code to line 105 and test it:

```
var autoplay;
document.querySelector('#autoplay').onclick = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    autoplay = setInterval(function() {
      arrowRight.click();
    }, 2000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(autoplay);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just removed the console.log. Are you sure that you've assigned `id` to the checkbox? It works for me.

Comment: EDIT: thanks for the answer,
had a typo in there, the thing is now the pics are autosliding till the end but at the last pic it stops & if I uncheck the box and click one of the arrows it still keeps autosliding and I get this on the console " TypeError: sliderImages[(current + 1)] is undefined[Learn More] main.js:168:5
slideRigh"